# Docker image not exposing ports using host network mode

Tags: docker

I was trying to use the `host`networking mode, which is supposed to share the same networking namespace as the Docker host, according to https://docs.docker.com/network/host/.

However, when I use `nc` to listen in on a port within the image, I'm unable to see that port listening on the host.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM kalilinux/kali-rolling

LABEL version="1.0" \
      author="[Redacted Author]" \
      description="Kali Docker Image"

RUN echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "kali-docker" > /etc/hostname && \
    set -x && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get install -yqq vim telnet nmap metasploit-framework sqlmap wpscan netcat

WORKDIR /root
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  kali:
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./kali-root:/root
    tty: true
    privileged: true
```

I built and ran the image in the following manner:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

When I run `nc -lvnp 80` from within the image, I'm unable to see anything on the host. Example:

```
root@kali:~/kali# docker-compose exec kali bash
root@29613f1a15fe:~# nc -lvnp 80
Listening on 0.0.0.0 80
```

and on the host:

```
root@kali:~# netstat -antp | grep -i listen
root@kali:~#
```

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: It looks like you're setting `network: host` in your `build` stanza, which doesn't make any sense (because network mode is a runtime configuration, not a build-time configuration). I think you want to move that `network` statement out of the `build` config and place it at the same level as `volumes`, etc.

Comment: It doesn't like "network" -- complains about the config option. Seems like it needs to go in the build section according to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/, version 3.4 of the docker-compose.yml

Comment: You're misreading the documentation. Setting `network` in the `build` config only impacts the network environment of your `RUN` commands when building the image. It has no impact on the running container. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode for what you want.

Comment: (You shouldn't need host networking at all, especially for a simple HTTP server; just use the Compose `ports:` declaration to publish your service's externally visible ports.)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. I know about exposing ports that way, but I am actually trying to accomplish a lot more than just ports that setting the `network: host` is supposed to provide. Just was trying to figure it out from a basic troubleshooting perspective.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Makes sense. I think I'm trying to figure out how to get it to work even on build, so this makes sense and clarifies what I was confused about. Thanks!